# ng-cordova preference (shared-preferences) is not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-sharedpreferences

I am new to Cordova + Ionic and trying to access shared-preferences in my android device via ngcordova preferences methods but I am getting this error in cordova 6.00| ionic 1.7.14  even all required configuration has been done. (according to my knowledge and please correct me if I am incorrect). Source codes of app.js and Index.html has been attached. Please help.

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaPreferences) {





$scope.storedata = function() {
   
    $cordovaPreferences.store('key', 'myMagicValue')
      .success(function(value) {
        alert("Success: " + value);
      })
      .error(function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error);
      }
      )
      
  };





  $scope.fetch = function() {
    $cordovaPreferences.fetch('key')
      .success(function(value) {
        alert("Success: " + value);
      })
      .error(function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error);
      })
  };


})

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>


    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type="button" value="ClikMe" ng-click="storedata()" ></input>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the error log.

```
TypeError: $cordovaPreferences.store is not a function
at Scope.$scope.storedata (app.js:32)
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:26457), <anonymous>:4:218)
at ionic.bundle.js:62386
at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:29158)
at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:29257)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:62385)
at HTMLInputElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16583)
at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2948)
at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2937)
at HTMLDocument.tapMouseUp (ionic.bundle.js:3013)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:25642(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:22421Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:29259(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:62385eventHandler @ ionic.bundle.js:16583triggerMouseEvent @ ionic.bundle.js:2948tapClick @ ionic.bundle.js:2937tapMouseUp @ ionic.bundle.js:3013
```

Comment: add some code, how you are using shared preferences..?its hard to guess..what might be wrong.!add controller code..!

Comment: do you get this error on android device or emulator?

Comment: I am getting this error in my local machine / Chrome browser but have tested the app in my android device too and both cases, the error comes from "$cordovaPreferences.store('key', 'myMagicValue')" in app.js

Comment: @Ajantha1311 Did you figure out solution for this issue ?